# What is MSDeploy.MSDeployProviderOptions in archive.xml?

Tags: xml, azure-devops, deserialization, msdeploy

Artifacts published by my Azure DevOps pipeline contains an archive.xml file. This contains a XML attribute called MSDeploy.MSDeployProviderOptions with a cryptic value. Is there a way to decode the value to a readable format? I want to know what information it contains and make sure that it is not sensitive from a security perspective.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`MSDeploy.MSDeployProviderOptions` is only the encoded version of the parameters provided to the provider at the time of packaging, such as `-source:dirPath=c:\,ignoreErrors=0x10293847 -dest:package=package.zip` will pack the `ignoreErrors` value.

Comment: Thanks. Is there a way for me to decode my values? I want to check since msdeploy.exe can accept credentials.

Comment: Hi @GabrielSmoljár, For the latest issue, we recommend you raise a new ticket for it and add the tag msdeploy. Thanks.

Comment: Where should I raise the ticket? I was referred to Stack Overflow because my employer does not have Azure support subscription.

Comment: Just raise a new ticket in the Stack Overflow and add the tag `msdeploy` and `xml`. Since I am not an msdeploy expert, I do not know how to decode the value. Thanks.

Comment: OK thanks. I have raised a new ticket here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66075762/how-to-decode-msdeploy-msdeployprovideroptions

Comment: Hi @GabrielSmoljár, Thanks for sharing, they will check the questions and provide you with detailed answers. In addition, if my answer is helpful to the original question, would you mind accepting it? Have a nice day.