# How to decode MSDeploy.MSDeployProviderOptions?

Tags: xml, msdeploy

Artifacts published by my Azure DevOps pipeline contains an archive.xml file. This contains a XML attribute called MSDeploy.MSDeployProviderOptions with a cryptic value. How do I decode the value to a human readable format?

Comment: I was not able to decode the content, however in my case I was able to simulate the results. The deployment of the webpackage was testable using msdeploys `/T` flag, without applying the changes. This showed, that my changes were not part of the arguments.